# SASL library for .net

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication, sasl

I am searching for a [sasl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) library for .net.

So far I could only find: [Sasl.Net](http://code.google.com/p/saslnet/) but it looks dead and only implements plain and digest-md5.

Can anyone suggest a good library? Preferably an open-source implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can be updated.  There is now the S22.SASL library for .NET which is much more complete.

https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Sasl

Comment: Thanks, do you have any experiance with it?

Comment: Very limited, I've been working on using it for SASL authentication against Irc, but I haven't spent much time on it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get this funcaiontly you will likly have to use a [Python SASL library](http://www.packtpub.com/article/installing-and-configuring-the-python-ldap-library-and-binding-to-an-ldap-directory) along with [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).

Comment: looks like a viable solution. I have no experience with IronPython nor python. Do you have experience in porting python to ironpython? Would it be a lot of work?